# Sub functions ml

Tags: function, ml

So I'm trying to do an assignment for an ml course, the issue is that the function requires a set type: `int * int -> int` for example, and the way that I see to solve the problem is to use another function (say for iteration) to solve the problem.

I believe that lisp has some kind of way of having a function be in scope for only one other function.

I think that this could be done:

```
fun a (x, y) = 
  let
     fun b (i,j) = ...;
  in
  ...;
```

[Not sure of exact syntax for this but I remember reading something like this only it was for temporary variables (which could be functions?]

but please correct me if this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ML, functions are first class citizens (i.e. values). You can bind them via `let` just like any other value.

Therefore, your idea is correct. It is especially a good design for functions passed as "iterators" (i.e. to map/fold/iter). Your question is too vague however for any further advise.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question I just wasn't sure what even to google.